# How to properly interpret the train and val loss?

Tags: neural-network, rnn

I am currently doing some research in neural networks for regression problems. Following some plots of the train and validation loss of different models. The blue line is the train loss and the orange line the validation loss.

2x 1000 Dense layers: 
[image]
It seems like the model is not complex enough to model the validation data. Is that right?

2x 2000 Dense layers: 
[image] 
The same as for the model before, but a little bit better. So a too complex dataset for the model. Is that true?

2x 1000 Recurrent layers: 
[image]
Alot better then the models before, but maybe still not enough epochs for the data or not complex enough model. True?

2x 2000 Recurrent layers: 
[image]
A little  bit better, however there are still validation data points that are not modelled properly. Do you have any suggestions how to get a better model?

Comment: Increasing the model capacity would resolve an underfitting problem, but that's not the situation these plots suggest. Also, you did not mention any dropout or any other element that changes its behavior from training to inference modes, so I don't understand how you get a validation loss that is lower than the training loss. Are you sure that the training/validation data split has been done correctly? Apart from that, how often do you compute the validation loss? I would expect a much denser training loss curve. Something seems very wrong in these plots to me.

Comment: On these models was no dropout activated. What I forgot to mention is that the Mae is plotted on the y axis. The splitting of the data was done with the keras function, so should be correct.